# How can I replace an existing pergola supporting mature wisteria?

Tags: replacement, pergola

We moved into a home with a 15-year old wooden pergola that is supporting mature summer wisteria vines. Most of the "beams" are 2x4s, all the beams are sagging, and the wooden lattice roof is rotting and falling down. The whole thing needs to be replaced with a sturdy structure.

What is the best way to replace the pergola while preserving the wisteria?

Edit: Adding more photos of the underside/damage. The posts seem to be okay.

[image: Front View]

[image: Side view, looking at the rear]

[image: Spot with lattice just about gone]

[image: Angle of the warp on the main beam]

[image: Crossbeam]

Comment: I'm sure the additional pics will help, but I'm not the expert in this area. It may well be worth the money to call in a landscape company to advise you on how to move, trim or adjust the Wysteria in order to keep it alive while you're working under it. You may discover that it's not worth the time/effort/expense to do so, though, and that it would be better to remove the whole thing and start the growing after it's been rebuilt. **Wait to see if someone else chimes in with an actual answer, though.**

Comment: Well you are lucky wisteria grows like a weed. It is possible to replace sections Or pieces 1 at a time but I would not try and replace the lattice the wisteria will fill in any areas that have voids within a few years and it grows so fast it will crush any new lattice just as it did to the old. The reason  your wood is sagging is it was not designed for so much weight, so your repairs will probably moving to wider boards 2x6 where the 2x4 are and 2x10 were the 2x6 are with several extra 2x 6 to reduce the span since putting lattice up will be impossible unless the plant is severely cut back.

Comment: the lattice roof is probably not necessary

Comment: Can it be untangled and laid aside while you do the work?

Answer (score 0):

Install new posts outside existing posts. Add parallel double 2x12 to new posts making sure 2x12 is exact height of top of all wood structures but below plant. Slide 2x12 rafter on its side across from new supports ontop the parallel 2x12s mount 2x4 at end of slid in 2x12 rafter and use as fulcrum to lift plant off existing structure and turn upright keep adding 2x12s as rafters. Install if needed trellis from under with cleats. That's how we did it at my grandmothers years ago, not saying its right but it works.